# Golang http request specify host in POST path

Tags: http, go, post

I'm performing the following request in golang:

```
request := &http.Request{
        URL:           url,
        Body:          requestBody, //io.ReadCloser containing the body
        Method:        http.MethodPost,
        ContentLength: int64(len(postBody)),
        Header:        make(http.Header),
        Proto:         "HTTP/1.1",
        ProtoMajor:    1,
        ProtoMinor:    1,
    }

res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)

//Printing the request:
dump, dumpErr := httputil.DumpRequest(request, true)
if dumpErr != nil {
   log.Fatal("Cannot dump the request")
}
log.Println(string(dump))
```

I want **the host to be specified** also in the **path of the post request**. Is it possible?

Expected result:

```
POST "http://127.0.0.1:10019/system?action=add_servers" HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:10019
Accept: "*/*"
Connection: keep-alive
```

Actual result:

```
POST "/system?action=add_servers" HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:10019
Accept: "*/*"
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [Request.URL](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.URL) to an [opaque URL](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#URL.Opaque).  The opaque URL is written to the request line as is.

```
request := &http.Request{
        URL:           &url.URL{Opaque: "http://127.0.0.1:10019/system?action=add_servers"}
        Body:          requestBody, //io.ReadCloser containing the body
        Method:        http.MethodPost,
        ContentLength: int64(len(postBody)),
        Header:        make(http.Header),
        Proto:         "HTTP/1.1",
        ProtoMajor:    1,
        ProtoMinor:    1,
    }
```

The [http.NewRequest](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequest) and [http.NewRequestContext](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#NewRequestContext) functions are the preferred way to create a request value. Set Request.URL to the opaque URL after creating the request with one of these functions:

```
u := "http://127.0.0.1:10019/system?action=add_servers"
request, err := http.NewRequest("POST", u, requestBody)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
request.URL = &url.URL{Opaque: u}

res, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

what value of the URL variable?
I think you can define the URL variable use a specific host

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:10019/system?action=add_servers"
```

In case your path is dynamic from another variable, you can use `fmt.Sprintf`, like below

```
// assume url value
var path = "/system?action=add_servers" 
url = fmt.Sprintf("http://127.0.0.1:10019/%s", path)
```

Comment: The question is not about the path / URL to post to, it's about the URL in the POST line of the HTTP protocol.